# How to use rails ActiveRecord to perform a left join of a Model with a subquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am using rails 5.  When I perform the following straight SQL query in the rails console, I get the following expected result:

```
    2.3.5 :053 >   w = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query("SELECT * FROM students s LEFT JOIN (SELECT student_id, MAX(urgent) AS has_urgent,MAX(created_at) AS last_contact FROM reports GROUP BY student_id) r ON r.student_id = s.id")
   (0.5ms)  SELECT * FROM students s LEFT JOIN (SELECT student_id, MAX(urgent) AS has_urgent,MAX(created_at) AS last_contact FROM reports GROUP BY student_id) r ON r.student_id = s.id
 => #<ActiveRecord::Result:0x00000000051e1518 @columns=["id", "name", "cwid", "email", "phone", "company", "role", "advisor", "advisor_email", "mentor", "created_at", "updated_at", "student_id", "has_urgent", "last_contact"], @rows=[[1, "Johnny Smith", "71419940", "jsmith@gmail.com", "8435550001", "foxtrot", "mentor", "John I. Moore, Jr.", "john.moore@citadel.edu", "", "2017-11-13 14:58:50.128114", "2017-11-13 14:58:50.128168", nil, nil, nil], [2, "Shelly", "12345678", "shelly@gmail.com", "8435550002", "bravo", "mentee", "Michael P. Verdicchio", "mv@citadel.edu", "Johnny Smith", "2017-11-13 14:58:50.160195", "2017-11-13 14:58:50.160243", "2", "t", "2017-11-13 14:58:50.210105"], [3, "Max", "87654321", "max@gmail.com", "8435550003", "palmetto", "unassigned", "Mei-Qin Chen", "mei.chen@citadel.edu", "", "2017-11-13 14:58:50.179220", "2017-11-13 14:58:50.179258", nil, nil, nil], [4, "George", "87654325", "george@gmail.com", "8435550004", "palmetto", "mentee", "Deepti Joshi", "djoshi@citadel.edu", "Johnny Smith", "2017-11-13 14:58:50.189733", "2017-11-13 14:58:50.189762", "4", "f", "2017-11-03 14:58:50.260914"]], @hash_rows=nil, @column_types={}>
```

However, this returns an ActiveRecord::Result type, but I really want is to use the Rails ActiveRecord to do the same query but return an ActiveRecord::Relation instead, I thought like so:

```
2.3.5 :054 > w = Student.joins("LEFT JOIN (SELECT student_id, MAX(urgent) AS has_urgent,MAX(created_at) AS last_contact FROM reports GROUP BY student_id) r ON r.student_id = students.id")
  Student Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "students".* FROM "students" LEFT JOIN (SELECT student_id, MAX(urgent) AS has_urgent,MAX(created_at) AS last_contact FROM reports GROUP BY student_id) r ON r.student_id = students.id LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Student id: 1, name: "Johnny Smith", cwid: "71419940", email: "jsmith@gmail.com", phone: "8435550001", company: "foxtrot", role: "mentor", advisor: "John I. Moore, Jr.", advisor_email: "john.moore@citadel.edu", mentor: "", created_at: "2017-11-13 14:58:50", updated_at: "2017-11-13 14:58:50">, #<Student id: 2, name: "Shelly", cwid: "12345678", email: "shelly@gmail.com", phone: "8435550002", company: "bravo", role: "mentee", advisor: "Michael P. Verdicchio", advisor_email: "mv@citadel.edu", mentor: "Johnny Smith", created_at: "2017-11-13 14:58:50", updated_at: "2017-11-13 14:58:50">, #<Student id: 3, name: "Max", cwid: "87654321", email: "max@gmail.com", phone: "8435550003", company: "palmetto", role: "unassigned", advisor: "Mei-Qin Chen", advisor_email: "mei.chen@citadel.edu", mentor: "", created_at: "2017-11-13 14:58:50", updated_at: "2017-11-13 14:58:50">, #<Student id: 4, name: "George", cwid: "87654325", email: "george@gmail.com", phone: "8435550004", company: "palmetto", role: "mentee", advisor: "Deepti Joshi", advisor_email: "djoshi@citadel.edu", mentor: "Johnny Smith", created_at: "2017-11-13 14:58:50", updated_at: "2017-11-13 14:58:50">]>
```

For this second approach, the Right table columns do not appear in the result, even though the generated SQL looks very similar.  I am new to Rails and ActiveRecord, so if someone can help me understand why these two results are different and what I should do to make the second ActiveRecord query work like the straight SQL query I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rails 5 then use `left_joins or left_outer_joins`.
Try this and let me know if it work for you.

`Student.left_outer_joins(:reports).select("student.*,  MAX(urgent) AS has_urgent,MAX(created_at) AS last_contact").group("student.id")`.

---

If you want to go with your first approach then these methods may helpful for you.

1. `result.columns` #Get the column names of the result.
2. `result.rows` #Get the record values of the result.
3. `result.to_hash` #Get an array of hashes representing the result (column => value)
4. `#ActiveRecord::Result also includes Enumerable`.

Comment: The problem I was having is that the columns from the inner select were not appearing in the result.  Being new at this, I just assumed the result of the join would expose all columns from both the left and right tables in the join.  I wound up having to tack on a .select('*,r.has_urgent,r.last_contact') at the end to get them in the results. Not sure whey this was necessary, but it worked.